# Vim - onoremap from learnvimscriptthehardway doesnt work in my case

Tags: vim

As i have read the book. I have encounter the onoremap comman, especially this one:
`:onoremap in( :<c-u>normal! f(vi(<cr>`. But when i pressed `din<shift>9`, where `<shift>9` is parenthesis, to delete content of next argument in parenthesis, nothing happened - just cursor moved up one line. Same here : `:onoremap il( :<c-u>normal! F)vi(<cr>` where cursos Find backwards the parethesis, but did nothing more.
It is weird, and even more strange because it worked few days ago (nothing has changed). What can be the problem?

I have even used `vim -u NONE <somefile>`, without loading .vimrc, random file with parethesis inside, and map it once again `:onoremap in( :<c-u>normal! f(vi(<cr>`, but even then didnt work. I reallt dont get it.

`verb omap in(` :

```
o  in(         * :<C-U>normal! f(vi(<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

```
1) .VIMRC:

    enter code 
:set nocompatible
:set helpheight=9999
:set matchtime=1
:set tabstop=3
:set autoindent
:set smartindent
:set shiftwidth=3
:set laststatus=2
:set fillchars=""
:set timeoutlen=300
"}}}

"statusline{{{
:set statusline=%f
:set statusline+=%=
:set statusline+=%l
:set statusline+=/
:set statusline+=%L
"}}}

"colorscheme{{{
:colorscheme elflord
:hi Folded guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE guifg=Yellow
"}}}

"leader and localleader{{{
:let mapleader = ","
:let maplocalleader = ";"
"}}}

"edit and source $MYVIMRC{{{
:nnoremap <leader>e :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>ee :tabedit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>s :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
"}}}

"movements with arrows{{{
:nnoremap - <c-d>
:vnoremap <left> <Nop>
:vnoremap <right> <Nop>
:vnoremap <up> <Nop>
"}}}

"vnoremap <VISUAL>{{{
:vnoremap <leader>" <esc>`>a"<esc>`<i"<esc>lel
:vnoremap jk <esc> 
:vnoremap Y "+y
"}}}

"inoremap <INSERT>{{{
:inoremap /<cr> <esc>A<cr>//
:inoremap <leader><cr> <esc>$a<cr>
:inoremap <c-d> <esc>ddi
:inoremap uu <esc>viwUea
:inoremap <leader>x <esc>:wq<cr>
:inoremap <c-h> <esc>hhviwxi
:inoremap <leader>m <esc> 
:inoremap <leader>d <esc>dd
:inoremap <leader>ee <esc>:tabedit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:inoremap <leader>c <esc>:
:inoremap cls <esc>G$vggx
:cnoremap <C-DEL> <s-right><c-w>
"}}}

"nnoremap <NORMAL>{{{
:nnoremap <F2> :set wrap!<cr>
:nnoremap tn :tabnew<cr>
:nnoremap bd :bd!<cr> 
:nnoremap <left> :w<cr>:bnext<cr>
:nnoremap <right> :w<cr>:bprevious<cr>
:nnoremap <leader><down> :<down>
:nnoremap <leader><up> :<up>
:nnoremap bn :w<cr>:new new<cr><c-w>j<c-w>c
:nnoremap <F1> :Explore<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>m q
:nnoremap <F10> :set nornu!<cr>:set nonu!<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>x :wq<cr>
:nnoremap P "+p
:nnoremap <leader>] <c-w>l
:nnoremap <leader>[ <c-w>h
:nnoremap <leader>r :reg<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>} :tabp<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>{ :tabn<cr>
:nnoremap <BS> i<BS>
:nnoremap <cr> $a<cr><esc>
:nnoremap <tab> i<tab><esc>
:nnoremap cls G$vggx
:nnoremap H 0
:nnoremap L $
:nnoremap q :q!<cr>
:nnoremap r <c-r>
:nnoremap <localleader>s :w<cr>:source %<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>; :exe "normal! mqA;\e`q"<cr>
:nnoremap <F12> :set incsearch!<cr>:set hls!<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>sp :match Error /\s\+/<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>no :match none<cr>
:nnoremap / /\v
:nnoremap gj :cnext!<cr>
:nnoremap gk :cprevious!<cr>
:nnoremap <c-a> Gvgg
"}}}

"cnoremap <COMMAND> {{{
cnoremap <c-h> <c-w>
cnoremap <a-h> <C-E><C-U>
cnoremap <C-DEL> <s-right><c-w>
"}}}

"onoremap <PENDING>{{{
:onoremap il( :<C-u>normal! F)vi(<cr>
:onoremap in( :<C-u>normal! f(vi(<cr>
:onoremap in{ :<C-u>normal! f{vi{<cr>
:onoremap in[ :<C-u>normal! f[vi[<cr>
:onoremap in" :<C-u>normal! f"vi"<cr>
:onoremap in' :<C-u>normal! f'vi'<cr>
:onoremap in< :<C-u>normal! f<vi<<cr>
:onoremap in` :<C-u>normal! f`vi`<cr>
:onoremap il{ :<C-u>normal! F}vi{<cr>
:onoremap il[ :<C-u>normal! F]vi[<cr>
:onoremap il" :<C-u>normal! F"vi"<cr>
:onoremap il' :<C-u>normal! F']i'<cr>
:onoremap il< :<C-u>normal! F>vi<<cr>
:onoremap il` :<C-u>normal! F`vi`<cr>
"}}}

"autocmd filetype_vim{{{
augroup filetype_vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vim setlocal foldmethod=marker
augroup END
" }}}

"autocmd filetype_c{{{
augroup filetype_c
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c inoremap <buffer> <localleader>c /**/<esc>hi
    autocmd FileType c iabbrev <buffer> main #include <stdio.h><cr>#include <stdlib.h><cr><cr>int main (void) {<cr><cr><cr>return 0;<cr>}<cr><esc>4ki<Tab>
    autocmd FileType c nnoremap <F5> :w<cr>:!clear;gcc -lm -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g % <cr>:!./a.out<cr>
    autocmd FileType c nnoremap <F6> :w<cr>:!clear;gcc -pthread %<cr>:!./a.out<cr>
    autocmd FileType c iabbrev <buffer><silent> pr printf("\n");<esc>2F"a<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
    autocmd FileType c inoremap <leader>a <esc>f"a,
    autocmd FileType c iabbrev <buffer><silent> sc scanf(" %");<esc>F"i<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
    autocmd FileType c inoremap <leader>u <esc>kkkO<CR>
    autocmd FileType c iabbrev for for(int i =0; i< ; i++)<esc>F<a<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
    autocmd FileType c iabbrev forj for (int j =0; j< ; j++)<esc>F<a<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
    augroup END
"}}}

"autocmd filetype_asm{{{
augroup filetype_asm
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType asm nnoremap <F5> :w<cr>:!clear;as --32 % -o 1.o;ld -m elf_i386 1.o -o 1<cr>:!./1<cr>
    autocmd FileType asm inoremap 3<cr> <cr>#<esc>a
augroup END
"}}}

"autocmd filetype_html{{{
augroup filetype_html
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType html nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>f Vatzf
augroup END
"}}}

"autocmd filetype_sh{{{
augroup filetype_sh
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype sh nnoremap <buffer> <F5> :w<cr>:!./%<cr>
augroup END
"}}}

"autocmd filetype_perl{{{
augroup filetype_perl
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype perl inoremap <leader>3 #!/usr/bin/perl<cr>
    autocmd Filetype perl nnoremap <leader>3 i#!/usr/bin/perl<cr>
    autocmd Filetype perl nnoremap <F5> :w<cr>:!clear;chmod +x %;./%<cr>
    autocmd FileType perl inoremap <F5> <esc>:w<cr>:!clear;chmod +x %;./%<cr>
    autocmd Filetype perl iabbrev pr print "\n";<esc>2F"a
    autocmd Filetype perl inoremap <leader>l <esc>f;s
    autocmd Filetype perl inoremap <localleader>s <esc>maggouse strict;<esc>`aa
    augroup END
"}}}
```

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem here.

Comment: how can i see how is vim interpreting my command? I mean, when i pressed the keys, how can i traced what is vim actually doing? Maybe that can help

Comment: @Kent the error is "Trailing characters", but i still dont get it why

Comment: First check the output of `verb omap in(`